# Google Apps Script regex to extract iframe tag containing a string and not containing string

Tags: regex

A Google Apps Script fetches url response. From the response, only iframe tag is to be extracted and other tags are not needed. Further, it should match iframe with string *dailymotion* to store results in dailymotion videos array and another which does not match *dailymotion* to store results in other vides array.

Below is response excerpt:

```
<section class="blog-post-content">
<h2 style="text-align: center;"><span class="wysiwyg-font-size-medium"><b>SomeThing</b></span><br></h2><div style="text-align: center;">
</div><p style="text-align: center;"></p><p style="text-align: left;"><span style="background-color: rgb(242, 195, 20);"><span style="color: rgb(192, 80, 77);">Disclaimer:</span></span><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Please note,</span><a href="http://www.foo.bar"><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">http://www.foo.bar</span></a><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"> or </span><a href="http://www.foo.bar"><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">www.foo.bar</span></a><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"> is only video embedding websites. All of the videos found here come from 3rd party video hosting sites such as YouTube, DailyMotion, zSHARE. We do not host any of the videos. Please contact to appropriate video hosting site for any video removal.</span></p>
<div style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">SomeThing Part 1<br><br></span></strong></div>
<div style="text-align: center;"><iframe src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/videoId1?autoplay=0&amp;logo=0&amp;hideInfos=0&amp;start=0&amp;syndication=202279&amp;foreground=&amp;highlight=&amp;background=" width="600" height="360" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
<div style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">SomeThing Part 2<br><br></span></strong></div>
<div style="text-align: center;"><iframe src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/videoId2?autoplay=0&amp;logo=0&amp;hideInfos=0&amp;start=0&amp;syndication=202279&amp;foreground=&amp;highlight=&amp;background=" width="600" height="360" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
<div style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">SomeThing Alternate Video- Part 1<br><br></span></strong></div>
<div style="text-align: center;"><iframe src="http://hqq.tv/player/embed_player.php?vid=videoId1&amp;autoplay=no" width="720" height="450" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
<div style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">SomeThing Alternate Video- Part 2<br><br></span></strong></div>
<div style="text-align: center;"><iframe src="http://hqq.tv/player/embed_player.php?vid=videoId2&amp;autoplay=no" width="720" height="450" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
</section>
```

Came up until here

Regex to match iframe tags with *dailymotion* videos

```
/<iframe(.*).*(daily).*\/iframe>/g
```

Regex to match iframe tags other than *dailymotion* with search string open or hqq.

```
/<iframe(.*).*(open|hqq).*\/iframe>/g
```

In this approach, excluding *dailymotion* means including something else like *open* or hqq. Those not having these three keywords may get missed.

The other way is to manage matched array elements by fetching all iframe tags and then push/pop the elements accordingly. This is going to bloat the code.

Still learning regex with negative lookahead.

Comment: What do you want to do? Merge the regexes into one?

Comment: `/<iframe(.*).*(daily|open|hqq).*\/iframe>/g`?

Comment: Thanks @karliwson and tiny-giant. Rephrased the question. Sorry for incorrect question at the start.